# "Overlay" Google Play Games Activities

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-games

I am using Google Play Game Services in my game, and the default Turn-Based UI it provides. My whole game is written in Libgdx, and I am not very well-versed in "core" Android UI stuff.

Now, when I launch a GPGS activity via startActivityForResult (for example, the match inbox UI), the Libgdx core thread is instantly paused. I cannot even play a click sound effect, since the sound is not played because the thread is paused.

Is there a way to make the GPGS activities somehow "overlayed", so that the Libgdx thread keeps running. Bonus question: can I also modify the animations of these activities?

Thanks!

Comment: In android you can use this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW